# Unobtrusive validation with dynamically loaded partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-validation

I'm loading partail view on button click

```
 function loadview(ele) {
        if (ele == 'account') {
           $('#updateprofile').load('@Url.Action("UpdateProfile", "Account")');
           $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($("#updateprofile"));
        }

        if (ele == 'password') {
           $('#changepassword').load('@Url.Action("ChangePassword", "Account")');
           $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($("#changepassword"));                
        }
   }
```

Validation is not working on partial view loaded by ajax request. However it works with `@Html.Partial("ChangePassword", Model.changepassword)`

Any help;

Comment: What do you mean by `dynamically created html validation`?

Comment: validation is not working on dynamically created html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to call the parse function in the callback function of `load`:

```
function loadview(ele) {
    if (ele == 'account') {
        $('#updateprofile').load('@Url.Action("UpdateProfile", "Account")', function () {
           $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($("#updateprofile"));
        });
    }
    if (ele == 'password') {
        $('#changepassword').load('@Url.Action("ChangePassword", "Account")', function () {
           $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($("#changepassword"));
        });
    }
}
```

Right now, you are calling the parse function before any content could be loaded.