# ASP.NET Core MVC Show hide partial views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, partial-views

I have a Contact/Index page split into two columns (for each column one PartialView). On the left I show the list of all my contacts and on the right the details of the selected/clicked contact from the said list.

...and the preview works great -> after a user clicks a record from the list I just call a '@Url.Action' for an action in my controller that returns a partial view with the details.

```html
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">
        <div id="sectionList">
          @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_PartialList", Model.Contacts);}
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
        <div id="sectionPreview" style="display: block">
          @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_PartialPreview", Model.Contact);}
        </div>

        <div id="sectionEdit" style="display: none">
          @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_PartialEdit", Model.Contact);}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

But I'm having a problem with 'edit'. On the details form I have a button for EDIT and when a users clicks it I want to HIDE the PartialView for preview (id="sectionPreview") and SHOW the one for edit (id="sectionEdit").

I already tried playing around with saving different styles (disply: block or none) to ViewBag and applying that to each section, but it doesn't feel like the right approach, because all the PartialViews (even with display set to none) still get rendered.

What is the best way/practice to make this work?

Comment: As a working solution/workaround I'm rendering both partialviews, but added a "Mode" variable to the model. In each partialview I check the "Mode" and return appropriate html code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach is to use ajax to load the partial view .On client side use ajax to call server side function and pass the filter parameter(id) . On server side , you can query the database with ID and return PartialView with models .

Then in success callback function of Ajax , you can load the html of partial view to related area in page using jQuery :

```
success: function (result) {
    $("#searchResultsGrid").html(result);
}
```

And hide related div like :

```
$("#sectionPreview").hide();
```

You can click [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51913.asp-net-core-mvc-how-to-load-a-partial-view.aspx) for code sample .

Comment: thank you. I'll take a look at the code sample and get back with the result

Comment: I took a closer look to what you suggest, but if I understand correctly when I hide/show partial views (sections) using ajax (jquery) all of the html code still gets rendered (even from the hidden partial views)?

Comment: @TheMixy , use javascript to show/hide the partial , if you don't want to render the other view , just delete the content in div : $("#div1").empty()

Comment: Thank you. Should I open a new thread for an additional question? (unobtrusive ajax validation does not show/work in ajax loaded partial view (edit) form...) ?

Comment: It's better to start new thread and post your current codes .

Comment: Thank you. I found a solution to the validation not showing in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22046168/unobtrusive-validation-with-dynamically-loaded-partial-view