# Render partial view on button click in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core

Based on which button is clicked i want to render a partial View inside a div element.
If button1 is clicked then Partial View1 is rendered and if button2 is clicked then Partial View2
is rendered.
How can i do it.

Main View:`enter code here`

```
<button id="button1">One</button>
<button id="button2">Two</button>

<div id="search">
//Render Partial view here based on which button is clicked.
</div>
```

Partial View1:

```html
<p>In Partial View1</p>
```

Partial View2:

```html
<p>In Partial View2</p>
```

---

After i click the blue button, i want partial page to be rendered in Div area below the blue button. But its rendering above the button in grey area which is my common layout area.

Before click
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7ww4.png)

After
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvBH2.png)

---

I tried this code but the problem is that partial view is loading but not within the div element.

```html
        <input id="btnSearch" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Search" />
        
        <div id="students">
           
        </div>

<script>
    $('#btnSearch').on('click',
        function (e) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/About',
                    type: 'POST',
                    cache: false,
                    async: true,
                dataType: "html"
                

                })
                .done(function(result) {
                    $('#students').html(result);
                }).fail(function(xhr) {
                    console.log('error : ' + xhr.status + ' - ' + xhr.statusText + ' - ' + xhr.responseText);
                });

        });

</script>
```

Comment: You have to work with client side library like jQuery or pure javascript and load html of view by ajax call and placeholder like div on the page. Look at similar answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56374272/asp-net-core-mvc-show-hide-partial-views

Comment: Thanks Oleg i tried below but the problem is that partial view is loading but not within the div element.

Answer (score 1):

I think the code you posted should work, but you need to query the right endpoint of your home controller.
Given your minimal modified code (see the ajax url):

```
        <input id="btnSearch" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Search" />

        <div id="students">

        </div>

<script>
    $('#btnSearch').on('click',
        function (e) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/View2',
                    type: 'POST',
                    cache: false,
                    async: true,
                dataType: "html"


                })
                .done(function(result) {
                    $('#students').html(result);
                }).fail(function(xhr) {
                    console.log('error : ' + xhr.status + ' - ' + xhr.statusText + ' - ' + xhr.responseText);
                });

        });

</script>
```

And your HomeController.cs should have such a second method:

```
public IActionResult View2(){
  return PartialView();
}
```

Edit I guess these pages could help you to get a rough idea of controllers and the handling:

- Controllers and Endpoints:
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/controller-methods-views?view=aspnetcore-3.0
- Adding a search: 
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/search?view=aspnetcore-3.0

  - But you are using a PartialView via jquery instead of returning a
    full view.
  - Your search Method should end with `return
    PartialView(....)`